# Move to start and end of text on home and end keys

Tags: vim

I want to be able to move to the start and to the end of the non-whitespace text of a line just by pressing `<home>` and `<end>`. I got it already up and running with `<home>`:

```
" <home> goes to the beginning of the text on first press and to the
" beginning of the line on second press. It alternates afterwards.
nn <expr> <home> virtcol('.') - 1 <= indent('.') && col('.') > 1 ? '0' : '_'
```

But I just can't get it up and running for `<end>`:

```
" <end> goes to the end of the text on first press and to the end of the line
" on second press.
nn <expr> <end> virtcol('.') < virtcol('$')-1 ? virtcol('$')-1 : winwidth(0)-1
```

The cursor does not move when I press `<end>`. But if I press `:` afterwards, the text `:.,.+x` appears, where `x` is the return value of the above expression. This command moves between lines and not between a column as it is intended by me.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the second case? As a note, I have to say that I have configured `virtualedit=all`, which means I can move the cursor after the length of the text of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your mapping simply returns either the number of the last column of the current line, or the width of the window, but it doesn't actually move the cursor.

You can use `$` and `|` to move the cursor on the line:

```
:nn <expr> <end> virtcol('.') == virtcol('$')-1 ? winwidth(0)-1.'\|' : '$'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get to the end of the non-whitespace text on first press you can try `g_` ([`:help g_`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#g_)).

```
" <end> goes to the end of the non-whitespace text on first press 
" and to the end of the line on second press.
:nn <expr> <end> virtcol('.') == searchpos('.*\zs\S','n')[1] ? winwidth(0)-1.'\|' : 'g_'
```

To find the place with last non-whitespace text you can use

- `searchpos()` function (returns the list with the line and column position of the match - therefore you need to append
- `[1]` to get just the number of the column - the second element of the list).
- `\S` means non-whitespace character,
- `\zs` sets the start of the match,
- `.*` means all characters before, as many as possible.